# Visualizing with ggplot yields different output using reprex vs. without reprex

Tags: r, ggplot2, reprex

I'm trying to add a segment in ggplot. However, adding `alpha` causes the segment to disappear. Although this is a known behavior that has been documented in many SO posts, I'm experiencing a particularly strange thing: when I generate the plot with `reprex()` I see the segment, but otherwise I don't.

### Example with `reprex()`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)


df_empty_circle <- 
  data.frame(x = 0,
             y = 0, 
             r = 1)


p_empty_circle <- 
  ggplot(df_empty_circle) + 
  geom_circle(mapping = aes(x0 = x, y0 = y, r = r)) + 
  coord_fixed() +
  theme_void()


p_no_alpha <- 
  p_empty_circle +
  annotate(geom = "segment", y = -1, yend = -1, x = -Inf, xend = 0)


p_no_alpha
```

[image]

```r
p_with_alpha <-
  p_empty_circle +
  annotate(geom = "segment", y = -1, yend = -1, x = -Inf, xend = 0, alpha = 0.2)

p_with_alpha
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

### Example when running code without `reprex`

Well, the same code as above, and the output is:

```r
p_no_alpha
```

[image: p_no_alpha_no_reprex]

```r
p_with_alpha
```

[image: p_with_alpha_no_reprex]

Why no segment in `p_with_alpha` when it's run outside `reprex()`?

*Session Info*

```r
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8.1 x64 (build 9600)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] reprex_2.0.0  dplyr_1.0.7   ggforce_0.3.3 ggplot2_3.3.5
```

---

Is there any explanation for this?

Comment: Given that you're running R on windows, [this](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4570) might be a relevant discussion.

Comment: Yup, you're right. When using `AGG` or `Cairo` as graphics device the problem is solved. Please consider posting this as an answer?